# argument of type 'function' is not iterable

Tags: django

The error "argument of type 'function' is not iterable" occurs in line: `if group in allowed_users:`

```
def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):

            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
            
            if group in allowed_users:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not authorized to view this Page')
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator
```

Comment: Error at if group in allowed_users:

Answer (score 1):

You should change to this:

```
if group in allowed_roles:
```

Instead of:

```
if group in allowed_users:
```

Because `allowed_users` is a function. Without `()` you just point to function without executing code inside. Functions themselves are not iterable, aren't they?